# Browsing the Address Space of an OPC UA Server

Tags: java, android, opc, opc-ua

I'm writing an Android App that can connect to a server, running on a PLC-machine.
I'm using the Prosys SDK and the OPC UA Java Stack for sure.

The app can show the important data from the server, so this is not the problem.

But what I want is that you can see the address space as a hierarchy and that you can browse through the whole address space like it is in UaExpert. So you can also see the data from the plc, if the server are supporting this functionality.
[This is a hierarchical order example which you can see in UaExpert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdAEO.png)

So how can I show the address space like this in Android? Because I think it's possible to get the whole address space, so I don't need to get every single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to get the whole AddressSpace with OPC UA and it will be completely inefficient to have such a feature.

You shall Browse the OPC UA Root Node (namespace=0, type=Numeric, identitifier=84 {RootFolder})

Based on the returned References, you shall then continue to Browse.

Expanding a collapsed Node shall trigger a new Browse Request.

Comment: I was speaking about the Root Node, like it is explained in most of the tutorials.